# A javascript to selectively block cookie creation by other javascript on page

Tags: javascript, cookies, httpcookie

I've wrote this javascript which blocks the creation of cookies by all the others javascript on page (I have jquery on page too):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  Object.defineProperty(document, 'cookie', {
    get: function () {
        return '';
    },
    set: function (value) {
    }
  });
});
```

Now I need to go a step further. I need to selectively block cookies, something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  Object.defineProperty(document, 'cookie', {
    get: function () {
        if (value == ...) {
          //call to "parent" function here  
        } else {
          return '';
        }
    },
    set: function (value) {
        if (value == ...) {
          //call to "parent" function here
          //document.cookie ???
        }         
    }
  });
});
```

Is it possible to call the "parent"/"native" function? I've tried with document.cookie but browser starts a loop, calling again my function (which is right).

Thanks in advance

Mariella

Comment: Are you trying it in security reasons? Redefining cookie getter/setter actually isn't secure at all and there is `HttpOnly` flag to block access to the cookie from DOM. Read more about [HttpOnly](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly) at OWASP.

Comment: This issue is related to new EU privacy law on cookies.  For example I need to prevent google analythics scripts to create cookies (_ga, _gat and so on) until user gives his consent.  I agree with you, it's something crazy, but to lawmakers don't matter!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that while your getter/setter proxy is active.

The problem is that `document.cookie` does not use JavaScript getters and setters, but (presumeably) native ones, which we can't access.
You can see that by calling `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`:

```
JSON.stringify(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(document, 'cookie'));
```

(I can't make this a snippet because snippets cannot access cookies.)
In Chrome:

```
{
    "value": "...",
    "writable": true,
    "enumerable": true,
    "configurable": true
}
```

In Firefox:

```
undefined
```

And without getting a hold of the function that handles the assignment, you have no means of calling it.

However, if you `delete document.cookie`, <s>Jon Skeet puts it</s> *it automagically reverts* back to normal.

So what you can do is store the assignments somewhere, delete your proxy at some point (`window.onunload` ultimately) and reassign everything to `document.cookie` there, like

```
function getCookies()
{
    var cookies = {};
    var list = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
    {
        var split = list[i].split('=');
        cookies[split[0].trim()] = split[1];
    }
    return cookies;
}

function hijackCookies()
{
    var cookies = getCookies();
    Object.defineProperty(document, 'cookie',
    {
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        get: function()
        {
            var list = [];
            for(var key in cookies)
            {
                list.push(key + '=' + cookies[key]);
            }
            return list.join('; ');
        },
        set: function(value)
        {
            var split = value.split('=');
            var key = split[0].trim();
            if(/* YOUR FILTER HERE */)
            {
                return;
            }
            cookies[key] = split[1];
        }
    });
    return function()
    {
        delete document.cookie;
        for(var key in cookies)
        {
            document.cookie = key + '=' + cookies[key];
        }
    };
}

var detach = hijackCookies();

// Do something with cookies or let 3rd party code run
// ...

detach();
```

[ [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7cdrLdy0/2/) ] (Note: Reloading the entire page and clicking "run" is **not** the same!)

Tested in Firefox 38.0.1 and Chrome 42.0.2311.152.

Comment: Hehe, used this to make one site GDPR compliant, `delete document.cookie` worked, but now after a few months, it doesn't reset native getter/setter back to normal anymore.

Comment: @Starwave what browser and version?

Comment: Woops, I made a mistake, was double checking now and this still works, sorry for false alarm! :)